# Is there an alternative to infinity?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, terminology, language, computation, infinity

We can say that a discrete set with 1 and 2 allows us to count just from 1 to 2 but a sequential set with 1 and 2 allows us to count from 1 to 2 in an infinite way (1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ...) but no man can count infinitely because people die.

A similar case happens in programming, if we create a while loop such as:

```
for (let i = 1; i > 0; i++) {
  console.log("Infinite loop");
}
```

It isn't really infinite because a computer can stop working (say, battery ran over).

---

Is this really a "lingual problem" in logic and anyway is there a slightly more accurate term than "infinity" to use here?

Comment: There is a position in the philosophy of mathematics called "finitism", which rejects the existence of completed infinities and maintains that infinity should be understood only as a limit. It is a minority view among mathematicians, since it involves a rejection of Cantor's approach to set theory.

Comment: [Potential infinity](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/thereals/potential.html) vs actual one?

Comment: @TankutBeygu thanks but no, it's a post with several questions which as a whole is just not what I ask for, therefore I clicked "no", it doesn't answer my question and I still expect a standalone answer.

Comment: See [Infinity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/infinity): According to Aristotle "The cosmos is finite, bodies are finite, geometrical segments are finite, each number is finite, etc. However, there are processes that can be iterated indefinitely, giving rise to what he called ‘potential infinity’. He claimed in fact that “in a sense [the infinite] is and in a sense it is not.”" Numbers are "names"; the "linguistic process" involved is the possibility of an *unlimited* iteration of the "plus one" operation (see your program above) that produces a new number form a previous one.

Comment: Regarding "an alternative to infinity" see [Finitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitism) and [Ultrafinitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafinitism)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one wants to avoid ontological commitments regarding actual/completed infinities, one can use the term "unbounded" or "indefinite" in order to refer to a computation or a process which has no known or definite (upper) limit, although it may not be actually Infinite (thus it may take an unknown but finite number of steps before termination)